# How to extract arguments used in a fitted nls model for use in a second fitting with do.call

Tags: r, nls, do.call

I am trying to use the same original arguments from a fitted `nls` model in the fitting of a second model using a subset of the data (for a cross validation exercise). I can retrieve the arguments (e.g. `fit$call`), but am having a hard time passing these arguments to `do.call`.

```
# original model ----------------------------------------------------------
# generate data
set.seed(1)
n <- 100
x <- sort(rlnorm(n, 1, 0.2))
y <- 0.1*x^3 * rlnorm(n, 0, 0.1)
df <- data.frame(x, y)
plot(y~x,df)

# fit model
fit <- nls(y ~ a*x^b, data=df, start=list(a=1,b=2), lower=list(a=0, b=0), algo="port")
summary(fit)
plot(y~x,df)
lines(df$x, predict(fit), col=4)



# perform model fit on subset with same starting arguments ----------------
# df sampled subset
dfsub <- df[sample(nrow(df), nrow(df)*0.5),]
dim(dfsub)
plot(y~x, dfsub)

ARGS <- fit$call # original call information
ARGS$data <- dfsub # substitute dfsub as data
ARGS <- as.list(ARGS) # change class from "call", to "list"

fitsub <- do.call(nls, args = ARGS )
# Error in xj[i] : invalid subscript type 'closure'
```

Also, as a side note, `fit$data` just returns the name of the data object. Is the data actually contained within the fitted `nls` object as well (as `lm` and other model fits sometimes do)?

Comment: side answer: no.  check out `str(fit)`.  the `data` element just contains the *symbol* for the data (`df` in this case). (`environment(fit$m$fitted)` has some stuff in it too, but not the data.

Comment: @BenBolker - Thanks for the side answer. Good to know I wasn't missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `update` to add a subset argument:

```
nr <- nrow(df)
update(fit, subset = sample(nr, nr * 0.5) )
```

Comment: Much easier than what I was doing! Seems to be a compatible approach with other models as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `update` function to refit the model with a different data set:

```
fitsub <- update(fit, data = dfsub)
```

Comment: +1 Thanks as well. I got two nearly identical suggestions, so had to award the correct answer to the one that arrived first.